# When I am considered as a customer?

Tags: consumer-protection, customer-service, refund

I have bought a digital service for 12 months now I want a refund because it didn't work but they told me that there is a law that says if i am not considered as a customer they can't refund me.

I strongly believe that they are on infraction to don't refund me if the service didn't work.

This was their answer:
As we informed your service was delivered and invoiced for you as a legal person and not a natural person, so the cancellation within 14 days is not possible.
The cancellation withing 14 days is possible for consumers. And by the Customer Rights Act the "Consumer" means an individual acting for purposes that are wholly or mainly outside that individual's trade, business, craft or profession.
Your services have been invoiced as a legal person which is not considered as a consumer. We are sorry, but we will not be able to fulfill your request.

---

What can I do now? I need a recommendation, I don't want to pay 12 months for a service that doesn't work.

Comment: Which country are you in? And what exactly does "it did not work" mean? The service was not usable for the purpose you intended it for or the service didn't work at all?

Comment: Also note the terminology: "Customer" here means "end user", typically a private person. It is customary that different terms apply for private persons and companies, so where you aware that you were buying this as a company? Why would they think you did?

Comment: Did you personally sign up for the service or did some company or other legal entity that you control do so?  Did you sign a contract?  Are there terms of service?  What do they say about the service not working?  What do you mean when you say it didn't work?

Comment: In the EU, Australia and UK there are quite strong "consumer protection" laws. Companies are not "consumers", although in many cases a seller will give companies, especially small companies, the benefits that "consumer protection" laws would give them.